# Apply conditional statement in javascript for print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a patient form. And I want to print the form before save into my database.
There is several types of fields in the form like `text`, `radio`, checkbox`.

Now I want to print only those `checkbox` which are `checked`, those `radio` button which are selected.

**html**

```js
var data = '<html><head><style media="print"></style></head><body><div class="row" style="border:2px solid #000;"><div class="col-md-12"><b>Name :</b>' + name + '</div><div class="col-md-6"><b>Gender :</b>' +
  if (sex == 1) {
    document.write("Male");
  } else
if (sex == 2) {
  document.write("Female");
} else {
  document.write("Other");
} + '</div><div class="col-md-6"><b>Age :</b>' + age + '</div><div class="col-md-12"><b>Mobile No : </b>' + mobile_no + '</div></div></body></html>';
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="form-first-name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="form-first-name" placeholder="name" class="form-first-name form-control require" id="name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="form-last-name">Age</label>
  <input type="number" name="form-last-name" placeholder="Age" class="form-last-name form-control require" id="age">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="form-last-name">Mobile Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="form-last-name" placeholder="Mobile Number" class="form-last-name form-control require" id="mobile_number">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="form-last-name">Religion</label>
  <input type="text" name="form-last-name" placeholder="Religion" class="form-last-name form-control require" id="religion">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="form-last-name">Occupation</label>
  <input type="text" name="form-last-name" placeholder="Occupation" class="form-last-name form-control require" id="occupation" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <h4>Gender</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Male<input class="col-md-4" type="radio" name="gender" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Female<input class="col-md-4" type="radio" name="gender" value="2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Other<input class="col-md-4" type="radio" name="gender" value="3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <h4>Marital status</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Married<input type="radio" class="col-md-4" name="marital_status" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Single<input type="radio" name="marital_status" class="col-md-4" value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I got no result though no error or anything show in my `console`.

What should I do ?

Comment: Which part of this is causing you problems? Or do you just want someone to write the code for you?

Comment: You can learn about .attr('checked') for a start.

Comment: this cannot work: `var someVar = 'string' + if ( ... ) { ... } + 'other string'`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen...updated my code about what causing problem

Comment: Also, several text inputs in your form have the same name. And the radio buttons for "Married" and "Single" have the same value.

Comment: @ArafatRahman `var someVar = 'string'; if (someCondition) { someVar += 'foo'; } else { someVar += 'bar'; } someVar += 'end';`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps,i used `serializeArray()`  to get all input values

```js
$("form").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault()
var data = $('form').serializeArray()
var data1 = '<html><head><style media="print"></style></head><body><div class="row" style="border:2px solid #000;"><div class="col-md-12"><b>Name :</b>'+data[0]['value']+'</div><div class="col-md-6"><b>Gender :</b>'+data[5]['value']+'</div><div class="col-md-6"><b>Age :</b>'+data[1]['value']+'</div><div class="col-md-12"><b>Mobile No : </b>'+data[2]['value']+'</div></div></body></html>';
console.log(data1)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="form-first-name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="form-first-name" placeholder="name" class="form-first-name form-control require" id="name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="form-last-name">Age</label>
  <input type="number" name="form-last-name" placeholder="Age" class="form-last-name form-control require" id="age">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="form-last-name">Mobile Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="form-last-name" placeholder="Mobile Number" class="form-last-name form-control require" id="mobile_number">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="form-last-name">Religion</label>
  <input type="text" name="form-last-name" placeholder="Religion" class="form-last-name form-control require" id="religion">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="form-last-name">Occupation</label>
  <input type="text" name="form-last-name" placeholder="Occupation" class="form-last-name form-control require" id="occupation" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <h4>Gender</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Male<input class="col-md-4" type="checkbox" name="gender" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Female<input class="col-md-4" type="checkbox" name="gender" value="2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Other<input class="col-md-4" type="checkbox" name="gender" value="3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <h4>Marital status</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Married<input type="checkbox" class="col-md-4" name="marital_status" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Single<input type="checkbox" name="marital_status" class="col-md-4" value="2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
 <form>
```

Comment: yes you show for raidio button but if i use checkbox and want to show those check box which is cheked then what to do ?